# Open multiple sockets on dynamic port range in Azure Service Fabric Application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

We have an application that we put in Azure Service Fabric. This application need to open multiple sockets on multiple port.
This application need to use some static port too. Is it possible in Service Fabric to work with dynamics ports for socket or did we need to put all port in `ServiceManifest.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it's true for both. Generally you need to specify all the endpoints in ServiceManifest that service should listen on, and then add a listener per each endpoint. As for dynamic ports, when you specify the endpoint you could leave the port empty so SF will pick some random one for you at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We don't want a random port but a wide range of port. For exemple 10000 port that we define with a start port and a end port. And after we define this range of port in LoadBalancer which is link to the SF.

Comment: Well, you could define your own port range. Check out [Network Isolation/Security with Azure Service Fabric](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/network-isolationsecurity-with-azure-service-fabric/) and [The relationship between Service Fabric node types and Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes).